# Fixed scrolled content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dom

I'm designing a dynamic web page that loads contents by AJAX, like the wall of facebook, first to the top last to the bottom. However, i don't want to change the scrolled content. For example, when new contents are loaded page is driven down, but i want a script to fix scrolled content on screen. How can I do this? Help me please.

**Update**

Okey, I've found the key function it is scrollBy(x,y); function of the window object. however now i want to use it with jquery animation how can i animate this function?

Comment: It sounds like you want to append new data to the existing data. What do you mean by fix scrolled content on screen.

Comment: I've merged your answer into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really know if this is what you want, but i think u can record the event's clientY attribute or pageY as in jquery, & then using jquery or simple JS scroll down to the value that you had stored.

Answer (score 0):

```
var w = $('#selector').width();
$('#selector').append(data).scrollTop(w);
```

i have not tested it but it has the basics on that :)

Comment: yep :$ this is embarrasing :)

Comment: or perhaphs it could be innerHeight

Comment: I was actually using this script, but it doesn't work well:
scrltop= $(window).scrollTop();
scrltop += $(t).height();
$(window).scrollTop(scrltop);

Comment: i think u looking for $('body,html');